# parse_args from reqparse flask_Restful returning error

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm using flask_restful and using reqparse to get params as an example:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse

path_params = reqparse.RequestParser()
path_params.add_argument("city", type=str)
path_params.add_argument("star_min", type=float)
path_params.add_argument("star_max", type=float)
path_params.add_argument("diary_max", type=float)
path_params.add_argument("diary_min", type=float)
path_params.add_argument("limit", type=float)
path_params.add_argument("offset", type=float)

       data = path_params.parse_args()
// returning error here : "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
```

What can I do to solve this, please?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the error when [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) or (`json.loads`) receives an empty JSON document to decode.

```py
import json

json.loads("")
# raises JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Without more of your code and especially request you sent, we cannot tell you more about your problem.

But, if I run the [full example](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#full-example) from the Flask-RESTful docs and request an empty JSON doc, I get the same error.

```bash
curl http://localhost:5000/todos -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '' -X POST
```

```json
{
    "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
}
```